# Checkboxes generated using aura:iteration is not clickable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, inputcheckboxes

I am trying to generate list of check boxes using the aura:iteration and list of checkboxes are getting displayed. But only the first checkbox is clickable and rest of the checkboxes i am not able to select/ not clickable. Any reason why they are not clickable?

```
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.data}" var="category">
            <div class="slds-checkbox">
                <input class="msg" type="checkbox" name="options" id="checkbox-unique-id-84" value="{!category.capCategory}" disabled="" />
                <label class="slds-checkbox__label" for="checkbox-unique-id-84">
                    <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
                    <span class="slds-form-element__label">{!category.capCategory}</span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </aura:iteration>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're giving all of your checkboxes the same html id. I believe you'll need to make this unique for each checkbox, normally by using some attribute of the current-row in the iteration:

```
<input class="msg" type="checkbox" name="options" id="**checkbox-unique-id-84**"...
```

Should be:

```
<input class="msg" type="checkbox" name="options" id="{category.something}"
```

You'll also want to update the 'for' property in the label.